# How to open grpc health check?

Tags: c++, grpc

I want to open health-checking on grpc server/client, but I do not find any example code. I found `EnableDefaultHealthCheckService` function in `health_check_service_interface.h` and call it before server start. But I do not know is it enough? Do I need do something else in client or server?

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
const grpc::string kHealthyService("healthy_service");

// Server code:
EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());

HealthCheckServiceInterface* service = server->GetHealthCheckService();
service->SetServingStatus(kHealthyService, true);

// Client code:
HealthCheckRequest request;
request.set_service(kHealthyService);

HealthCheckResponse response;
ClientContext context;
std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel = CreateChannel(server_address, InsecureChannelCredentials());
std::unique_ptr<Health::Stub> hc_stub = grpc::health::v1::Health::NewStub(channel);
Status s = hc_stub->Check(&context, request, &response);
EXPECT_EQ(Status::OK.error_code(), s.error_code());
if (s.ok()) {
    EXPECT_EQ(HealthCheckResponse::SERVING, response.status());
}

server->Shutdown();
```

> https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13962